# Unable to complete Eucalyptus Fast-Start 3.4.2 Cloud-In-A-Box Installation

Tags: linux, installation, cloud, eucalyptus, qt-faststart

I m new to Eucalyptus and trying to set up my small private cloud as a university research project. I m try to install Eucalyptus 3.4.2 via Fast-media installation & then selecting "Install centos 6 with Eucalyptus Cloud-in-a-box" from the boot menu. As I have very few knowledge about Static or DHCP settings, so instead of giving Static IPs etc, I choose ethh0 with DHCP and moved on to set my password and time zone. Now I m asked to give Public IP range/list where I entered the following values for IP RANGE:

192.168.184.128-192.168.184.200.

Then the next page appears where i selected "Replace existing Linux system" but on trying to go Next, the following error appears:

"An unhandled exception has occurred. This is most likely a bug. Please save a copy of the detailed exception and file a bug report."

And I m unable to handle this error because no matter I choose Debug or Save or Exit options for this bug/error, in every case the system shuts down n reboot and no further installation occurs. Please help me to go beyond this error to set up my cloud.

Regards,

Sumbul Khan

Answer (score 0):

Please try the 4.0 version using the new faststart. Install CentOS 6.5 minimal server in your system and use the following command to install Eucalyptus.

## bash <(curl -Ls eucalyptus.com/install)

Answer (score 0):

install centos 6.6 as cents 6.5 has a bug as far as i heard and those who installed centos 6.5 has upgraded the kernel to cent os 6.6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My solution was not to select "Replace existing Linux system", but to select "Create Custom Layout". Just create a root partition and a swap partiton manually.